# How do I make the UL appear over the other elements and extend outside of the box?

Tags: css

I want to have the UL appear over the other elements and to be able to extend past the boundaries of the box if the scroll position moves it out of view.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuw80cyn/)

This is what I want it to look like
[image]

Comment: If you remove z-index:0, the ul will appear over the list of boxes. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: More importantly I want to extend past the boundaries of the box if it gets cut off due to scrolling.

Comment: ^ Are you looking for `position: fixed` in combination with a bit of a `top` offset to do that? I'm still a little unsure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want the UL to extend past the border of the container element.  Imagine a dropdown and you open the dropdown and the elements are cut off because they're not scrolling into view.  Right now the container has overflow auto which also hides the UL.  I want to show the UL

Comment: @Smeegs set `overflow: auto;` to `overflow: visible;` to show the full list. You can't hide the list of divs inside a scroll list *and* show the UL outside the scroll list unless you use JavaScript.

Comment: @TylerH Let me fake what I want and post it to the question.  I think there is a lot of confusion here.

Comment: @TylerH: updated.

Comment: @Smeegs Yep, see my revised comment above. I'm assuming you also want the UL to retain its place (e.g. starting below the 3rd-to-last `.item` div)? If so, you're gonna need JavaScript. I don't think CSS can't handle multi-level descendants with so many different overflow and position properties.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured I'd have to use javascript but I really want to avoid it.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/kuw80cyn/2/ for how it would appear on hover if hidden initially

Comment: Thanks.  But it's still bound in the container element

Comment: Yep, and here's the only way I know of in CSS to make it escape the container element: doesn't quite work as intended either way: https://jsfiddle.net/kuw80cyn/3/

Comment: That's better.  I might be able to work with that.  Thanks